# MVC/PHP: Ideal way to handle validations and display messages in controller action?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, error-handling, exception

Colleagues and I were discussing ways to handle failed validations and display appropriate messages in a MVC framework controller action. All three of us had different opinions, but I thought my approach, Case 3, was ideal for handling errors in general. What are the pros and cons of these approaches?

**Case 1**: `action()` dictates error messages and if logics in `validate()` is used anywhere else, new error messages have to be written. It seems to be against the single responsibility principle in some way..

```
public function action()
{
    $errors = [];

    if ($this->validate($data)) {
        $errors[] = 'Check 1 failed';
    }
    // etc...
    // Display errors if $error isn't empty
}
```

**Case 2**: this one is just weird to me that `validate()` would return an object with different properties set on it for checking and displaying errors.

```
public function action()
{       
    $obj = $this->validate($data);  // property 'error' set if validation fails

    if (property_exists($obj, 'error')) {
        // Display errors if 'error' property is set
    }       
}
```

**Case 3**: `validate()` returns true or throws exception. As simple as that.

```
public function action()
{
    try {
        $this->validate($data); // throws some exception if fails
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Dispay caught error message
    }       
}
```

Comment: Potential answers would be "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: @musicliftsme: The `try{} catch(){}` should be **inside** the `$this->validate()` function and probably when catched an error, attach the error message to some kind of `class ErrorHolder`. Later on you can do `$errorHolder->getAllErrors();` to output them. The ways you suggested aren't really **MVC**

Comment: @Xatenev, that's a very good point. The framework we use already has an error handler, so `validate` can add the message to it (above the exact context we discussed for a few mins ad hoc). Then, I would just make it return `true` or `false` and just redirect the request in the action. Sounds about right?

Comment: @musicliftsme I posted you an example code how **I** would go about this. This is **my** opinion of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ErrorWrapper {
    private $errors;

    public static function getAllErrors() {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    public static function attachError($error) {
        $this->errors[] = $error;
    }

}

public function validate() {
    try {
        // validation logic
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        ErrorWrapper::attachError
    }
}

public function action()
{
    $this->validate($data);
}
```

You should probably try an approach like above. Basically your **CASE 3**, just in a more MVC Pattern.

Comment: Your answer is not valid PHP, you cannot use `$this` in a static function. `$errors` would need to be static and it would be `self::` Also, you never throw an exception so how are you supposed to catch it?